# Why does numpy.insert convert an (N, 1) array to an (N,) array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, subtraction

I have a numpy array with size (N,1). When I insert a value somewhere into the array using numpy.insert, it results in an (N,) array. This later causes problems when subtracting an (N,1) array from an (N,) array.

Example:

```
#Random (4 x 1) array
a = np.random.rand(4,1)

#Insert a number. This results in a (4,) array
b = np.insert(a,0,10)

#Some other (5 x 1) array
c = np.random.rand(5,1)

#Because c is (5,1) and b is (5,), this subtraction is not element by
#element and results in a (5,5) array.
d = b - c
```

Two questions:

1. Why does "insert" decrease the dimensions of the array?
2. Why does subtracting a (5,) array from a (5,1) array result in a (5,5) array rather than an element-wise subtraction?

Comment: Broadcasting: (5,) & (5,1) => (1,5) & (5,1) => (5,5)

Answer (score 1):

From the [`numpy.insert` docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html):

> **axis** : *int, optional*
>
> Axis along which to insert *values*. If *axis* is None then *arr* is flattened first.

You didn't specify an axis, so `insert` flattened the array as the first step. As for how the subtraction works, that's [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).